# Access Denied when creating signedUrl on Google Storage Object in App engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Exact text: "Access Denied. Caller does not have storage.objects.get access to object on (url)"

I currently have 2 projects on google services. One that is a resource for an Android/iOS app that will upload images to google cloud storage (more so firebase storage). The other is a node.js server that detects when an image is uploaded and sends an email with a signedUrl to that image.

The node.js server has the following google storage setup and function that is called:

```
var storage = require("@google-cloud/storage")({
   keyFilename: "google_secret.json",
   projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx' 
});

function getImageFromGcloud(x, y, time, date_string) {
    var bucket = storage.bucket('bucket-name');
    var storage_ref = 'Incomplete_Scans/' + date_string + "/" x + "_" + y + "_" + time + ".jpeg";

    bucket.file(storage_ref).getSignedUrl({
         action: 'read',
         expires: '03-17-2025'
    }, function(err, url) {
         if (err){
             console.error(err);
             return;
         }
         console.log("Sent email");
    });
}
```

The link provided from getSignedUrl used to work, when clicked it would open a new tab with the image there. However as of recently, it had just stopped. Perhaps it has to do with the permissions, however nothing I'm doing is working. Any ideas?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Is it possible that the service account whose key you are using to generate the signed URL has lost read access to the object?

Comment: It is possible. I may not be doing the whole bucket permissions incorrectly. I've added to the bucket permissions and object default permissions for viewers, editors, and owners of a project to have Owner permission. Is there something I'm missing? @BrandonYarbrough

Comment: Bucket permissions aren't hierarchical. They don't grant read permission on the objects inside the buckets. "Default object permissions" will, but only for new objects, and only by default. Try adding the service account explicitly to some object to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! <3 Please comment as an answer so I can mark it. @BrandonYarbrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a 403 (permission denied) instead of a 401 (Invalid authentication), it's likely that your service account that is signing requests had lost its access to the objects for some reason. Add read access to that service account.